# How to push to main,main and master are entirely different commit histories?

Tags: git, github

I tried this

```
$ git push origin/main master
fatal: 'origin/main' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Image from Github
[image]

Branches

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/main
  remotes/origin/master
```

I rebased

```
git pull --rebase origin main
From https://github.com/MilenkoMarkovic/propertyandroid
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
   387a216..a749c57  main       -> origin/main
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

But if I go for

```
$ git push -u origin master
To https://github.com/MilenkoMarkovic/propertyandroid.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/MilenkoMarkovic/propertyandroid.git'
hint: Updates were rejected
```

Why non-fast-forward?

How to make them equal or similar at least? Main was created by deafult.

Comment: Unclear what the goal is. The command `git push origin/main master` is meaningless as the remote is called `origin`. You have ended up with both master and main on your remote. What exactly would you like to do? Personally I would recommend merging or rebasing them locally into one and then deleting the other one. See my https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Comment: @matt I tried git rebase main,but I have main with 1 file(README) and master with 20 folders.

Comment: You lost me. Being on `master` and saying `git rebase main` should work perfectly. What went wrong when you tried it? Did you read the article I pointed you to?

Comment: @MikiBelavista: is the `main` just pre-filled dummy content and you simply want to get rid of it? Or is it a "real" readme?

Comment: @matt I read now your article, thanks, really nice piece of work.I will edit my post.

Comment: @JoachimSauer You can look at my repo,it has 2 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why non-fast-forward? How to make them equal or similar at least?

Because the rebase changed the commit hashes. Your mistake here was pushing master previously. Now you will have to push with force to replace it:

```
git push -u -f origin master
```

Now you are free to clean up and delete main. As my [article](https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/) explains, you will probably need to tell GitHub that the primary branch is master. Then you will be able to delete main both locally and at GitHub.